# Quitar tildes de los strings

Tags: java, string

tengo que quitar los tildes de un String para poder comprobar si es una vocal o es un carácter. La cosa es que si tiene tildes no me detecta con una vocal me detecta como un carácter y necesitaría saber el modo de quitar los tildes a un string.

```
package Cadenas;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario;
        System.out.println("Introduce un caracter");
        usuario=sc.nextLine();
        String aux=usuario.toLowerCase();

        if (aux.charAt(0)=='a' || aux.charAt(0)=='e' || aux.charAt(0)=='i' || aux.charAt(0)=='o' || aux.charAt(0)=='u') {
            System.out.println("Es una vocal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Es un caracter");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías buscar una vocal dentro de una cadena que contenga todas las vocales normales y acentuadas, escribes las vocales de todas las formas que puedan aparecer en el idioma para el que estás haciendo el programa, de tal manera que tendrías:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario;
        System.out.println("Introduce un caracter");
        usuario=sc.nextLine();
        String aux=usuario.toLowerCase();

        String vocales = "aeiouáéíóúàèìòùäëïöü"; // Cadena con todas las vocales acentuadas

        if (vocales.indexOf(aux.charAt(0)) > -1) { // Si está dentro de vocales
            System.out.println("Es una vocal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Es un caracter");
        }
    }
}
```

Te queda un código más limpio y más sencillo, usando funciones básicas.

Comment: Perdona pero podrías explicarme el >-1 no logro entenderlo. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando vocales.indexOf(caracter) es mayor de -1 indica que existe una coincidencia, indexOf te devuelve la posición del caracter dentro de vocales, es decir, si pruebas con "a" te devuelve 0, si te devuelve -1 te indica que no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la función Normalize para eliminar los acentos de tu string y replace para otros caracteres especiales. Te dejo una función que podría servirte:

```
public static String limpiarAcentos(String cadena) {
    String limpio = null;    
    String valor = cadena.toUpperCase();

    // Normalizar texto para eliminar acentos, dieresis y tildes
    limpio = Normalizer.normalize(valor, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

    // Quitar caracteres no ASCII excepto la enie, interrogacion que abre, exclamacion que abre, grados, U con dieresis.
    limpio = limpio.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}(N\u0303)(n\u0303)(\u00A1)(\u00BF)(\u00B0)(U\u0308)(u\u0308)]", "");

    // Regresar a la forma compuesta, para poder comparar la enie con la tabla de valores
    limpio = Normalizer.normalize(limpio, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    limpio = limpio.toLowerCase();

    return limpio;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: y no existe algún modo mas sencillo sin usar funciones externas externas?